# how to display half a picture in before Css

Tags: css

I used the chosen js plugin to create multiple selects.
I'm trying to customize its style. I want when item is not selected, there will be a small gray square on the left. If the item is selected, it will display a small blue square.
Currently I have an image that contains 2 small squares, I tried to show a square on the left, but it is showing both squares, I want it to only show the top half or the bottom half.
How can I do that?
Riding this is what I tried to try.

```
.chosen-container-multi.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop .chosen-results li::before {
            content: url('https://image.ibb.co/iLpwap/Selection_Icon.png');
            position: relative; 
            padding-right: 10px;
 }
```

[Display half a picture in before css](http://jsfiddle.net/L6kmd3rb/4/)

Comment: You can't do that with the image in the `content` property. You could do with a a background image *sprite* of the pseudo-element and then adjust the `background-position`

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vaMpXN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sprite sheet as the content to the `::before` pseudo element will not allow you to crop it in the way you desire.

Instead, use the sprite sheet as a background image and size your pseudo element appropriately.

In the selected state, reposition the background image so the blue area is visible.

```js
var config = {
   '.chosen-select': {},
   '.chosen-select-deselect': {
     allow_single_deselect: true
   },
   '.chosen-select-no-single': {
     disable_search_threshold: 10
   },
   '.chosen-select-no-results': {
     no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!'
   },
   '.chosen-select-rtl': {
     rtl: true
   },
   '.chosen-select-width': {
     width: '95%'
   }
 }
 for (var selector in config) {
   $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
 }
```

```css
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice {
   line-height: 30px !important;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 0 !important;
 }

 .chosen-container-multi.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop .chosen-results li::before {
   content: ""; /* Changed */
   position: relative;
   z-index: 100000;
   margin-right: 10px; /* Changed */
   display: inline-block; /* Added */
   width: 22px; /* Added */
   height: 24px; /* Added */
   background: url(https://image.ibb.co/iLpwap/Selection_Icon.png); /* Added */
 }

 .chosen-container-multi.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop .chosen-results li.result-selected::before {
   background-position: 0 -24px; /* Added */
 }

 .chosen-container-multi .chosen-drop .result-selected {
   color: #444 !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select chosen multiple data-placeholder="Select a item" class="chosen-select" style="width: 400px;">
    <option value="18">Item Test 1</option>
    <option value="19">Item Test 2</option>
    <option value="20">Item Test 3</option>
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Item</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code, can you check it

http://jsfiddle.net/L6kmd3rb/14/

```
 .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice {
line-height: 30px !important;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 0 !important;
}

.chosen-container-multi.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop .chosen-results li::before {
content: url('https://image.ibb.co/iLpwap/Selection_Icon.png');
position: relative; /*or absolute*/
 z-index: 100000; /*a number that's more than the modal box*/
 padding-right: 10px;
 height:20px;
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-drop .result-selected {
color: #444 !important;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That does not work. You aren't displaying the blue icon when the element is selected.